# How to listen selected port when vps is not available via port 80?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, port-forwarding

There is this situation:

Two vps running behind a single public ip address (using one router). 
Let's say vps 1 is:

`120.1.2.3:80 (default pot)`,

And vps 2 is:

`120.1.2.3:81 (non default port to reach vps 2)`.

There is also application that is listening to port `3210`.

The question, is how to connect to this software in vps 2? First I need somehow to pass through port 81.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Why would you use two vps with same ip? Please improve it.

Comment: Well, you are running two vps behind one public ip I suppose.

Comment: @bangal yes it is true

Answer (score 0):

You use a reverse proxy on the first VPS and have it proxy connections to the second on port 81 and to wherever port 3210 is located. Using name based virtual hosting on the first server to capture the incoming connections and distribute them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup. You didn't mention how currently are you able to reach vps2 at port 81 (port forwarding or reverse proxy ?).

If you are able to reach `vps2:81` using domain name or ip address, that means you already have a working rule for port vps2:81. All you need then is to find out and create a similar rule for `vps2:3210`. It can be a simple port forwarding at your router or reverse proxy configured at vps1.